# How can I use $resource to send a HTTP DELETE request to my server?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
var entityResource = $resource('/api/' + $scope.entityType + '/');

entityResource.delete(entityId,
   function (result) {
      $scope.remove($scope.grid.data, idColumn, entityId);
   }, function (result) {
      alert("Error: " + result);
   })
```

When the code executes I get the following message:

```
DELETE http://127.0.0.1:81/api/Subject 404 (Not Found) 

{"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://127.0.0.1:81/api/Subject'.","messageDetail
```

How can I make it so the $resource sends a DELETE with /api/Subject/123  Right now it seems to ignore the value of entityId

Here is what I tried so far after advice:

```
    var entityResource = $resource('/api/:entityType/:entityId',
           { entityType: '@type', entityId: '@id' });
    entityResource.delete({ type: $scope.entityType, id: entityId }, 
        function (result) {
            $scope.remove($scope.grid.data, idColumn, entityId);
            $scope.remove($scope.grid.backup, idColumn, entityId);
            $scope.close();
        }, function (result) {
            alert("Error: " + result);
        })
```

Unfortunately this give me: DELETE /api?id=12&type=Subject HTTP/1.1

Comment: Just as an FYI, `foo.delete()` is misinterpreted by older Internet Explorer versions and Android versions. It mistakes `delete` as a keyword and it fails. `foo["delete"]()` is a workaround, if your requirements need you to support them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the entity ID in your template:

```
var entityResource = $resource('/api/:entityType/:entityId', 
                               {type:'@entityType', id: '@entityId'});
```

Then when you call it, pass in the parameters:

```
entityResource.delete({type: $scope.entityType, id: entityId}, success, failure);
```

or

```
var entity = new entityResource({type: $scope.entityType, id: entityId});
entity.$delete(success, failure);
```

assuming that `success` and `failure` look loke this:

```
var success = function (result) {
    $scope.remove($scope.grid.data, idColumn, entityId);
};

var failure = function (result) {
    alert("Error: " + result);
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your example uses "success" and "failure". Can you add to your answer an example that has the two functions that I use if that's also a valid way.

Comment: `success` and `failure` are just callbacks.  You can do it inline as well (like you did), but it wasn't relevant to the solution, so I short-handed them.

Comment: I just tried your first solution and it gave me "DELETE /api?id=12&type=Subject HTTP/1.1"  You can see my exact code in the question after I used your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I got that mapping backwards.  It should be `{type:'@entityType', id: '@entityId'}`.  I updated my response to reflect this as well.